# Skip item if element doesn't exist on page

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

[Here](https://pastebin.com/FrVH5M9E) is my entire code.

```
response = requests.get("https://www.zomato.com/san-francisco/restaurants?q=restaurants&page=" + str(i),headers=headers)
content = response.content
bs = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

zomato_containers = bs.find_all("div", {"class": "search-snippet-card"})

for zomato_container in zomato_containers:
    title = zomato_container.find("a", {"class": "result-title"}).get_text()
    numVotes = zomato_container.select_one('[class^=rating-votes-div]').text  
    numVotes = numVotes[1] if len(numVotes) > 1 else numVotes[0]

    print("restaurant_title: ", title)
    print("numVotes: ", numVotes)
```

I get an error :

> "numVotes = zomato_container.select_one('[class^=rating-votes-div]').text AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

I am highly positive it's because some elements on the page do not exist. I am trying to skip those elements but cannot figure out how.

Thank you so much. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do `zomato_container.select_one('[class^=rating-votes-div]')` first, check if it's `None`, then do `.text` if it's not.

Comment: How about using `try` and `except`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be:

```
for zomato_container in zomato_containers:
    title = zomato_container.find("a", {"class": "result-title"}).get_text()
    try:
        numVotes = zomato_container.select_one('[class^=rating-votes-div]').text  
        numVotes = numVotes[1] if len(numVotes) > 1 else numVotes[0]
    except AttributeError:
        continue

    print("restaurant_title: ", title)
    print("numVotes: ", numVotes)
```

Comment: Would you advice I use try and except for all my elements just to be safe? Just in case the address, district, or cuisines are missing.

Comment: @Kay I wouldn't, you can wrap one `try/except` block or create a function that will do `zomato_container` stuff with `class` as argument maybe, but it depends.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if variable is None before attempting to access `text` property

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

i = 1
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get("https://www.zomato.com/san-francisco/restaurants?q=restaurants&page=" + str(i),headers=headers)
content = response.content
soup = bs(content, "html.parser")

zomato_containers = soup.select('.search-snippet-card')

for zomato_container in zomato_containers:
    title = zomato_container.find("a", {"class": "result-title"}).get_text()
    numVotes = zomato_container.select_one('[class^=rating-votes-div]')
    if numVotes is None:
        numVotes = 'N/A'
    else:
        numVotes = numVotes.text.strip()

    print("restaurant_title: ", title)
    print("numVotes: ", numVotes)
```

Comment: I should have reworded it correctly. I meant skip element, but go ahead and scrape the other elements such as address, district, etc. For the skipped elements, I want beautiful soup to put down "N/A". Do you happen to know how that can be done? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Please see edit. You can use same logic for each element.